# Trying to compare two lists in C# test

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core, automated-tests

I'm trying to write an automation test where the results from my API match my database.
Here is my current method:

```
public void GetScanCodes()
        {
            //Get Response from API
            var response = RequestBuilder.GetResponse("api/v1/item-scan-codes", Method.GET);

            //Verify Status Code
            string Expectedcode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            Console.Write(Expectedcode);
            Assert.AreEqual(Expectedcode, "OK", "Response code is " + response.StatusCode);

            var deserialize = new JsonDeserializer();
            var ListofItemScanCodes = deserialize.Deserialize<List<ItemScanCodesModel>>(response).ToList();
            Console.WriteLine("API output:::" + ListofItemScanCodes);

            string connString = dataRepo.BuildConnectionString();
            var dbResult = dataRepo.Query<ItemScanCodesModel>(connString, "InventoryMgmt_GetScanCodeReportDetails.sql");
            Console.WriteLine("DB output:::" + dbResult);

            //Comparison between API and DB result
            Assert.AreEqual(ListofItemScanCodes, dbResult, "List of results do not match");
            
        }
```

Here is the `ItemScanCodesModel`:

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace RO.Api.Models
{
    /// <summary>
    /// This model represents the Item Scancodes.
    /// </summary>
    public class ItemScanCodesModel
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// item scan codes item alias IID
        /// </summary>
        public Int64 ItemAliasIID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// name of item alias
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "Item alias cannot exceed 250 characters.")]
        public string ItemAlias { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// item scan codes item alias item IID
        /// </summary>
        public Int64 ItemAliasItemIID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// item scan codes NDC
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(250, ErrorMessage = "NDC cannot exceed 250 characters.")]
        public string NDC { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// item scan codes item IID
        /// </summary>
        public Int64 ItemIID { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// item scan codes item ID
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(50, ErrorMessage = "Item Id cannot exceed 50 characters.")]
        public string ItemId { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// generic name for the item
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(254, ErrorMessage = "Item generic name cannot exceed 254 characters.")]
        public string ItemGenericName { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// class of item
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(254, ErrorMessage = "Item class cannot exceed 254 characters.")]
        public string ItemClass { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// package qty
        /// </summary>
        public long? PackageQty { get; set; }
        /// <summary>
        /// shipping vendor
        /// </summary>
        [MaxLength(254, ErrorMessage = "Ship vendor cannot exceed 254 characters.")]
        public string ShipVendor { get; set; } 
        /// <summary>
        /// cost of unit
        /// </summary>
        public decimal? UnitOfIssueCost { get; set; }

    }
}
```

When I manually test this in postman the results match exactly how they are laid out in the database. When I run the test here is the error I receive:

```
Message: 
      List of results do not match
      Expected and actual are both <System.Collections.Generic.List`1[RO.Api.Models.ItemScanCodesModel]> with 97533 elements
      Values differ at index [0]
      Expected: <RO.Api.Models.ItemScanCodesModel>
      But was:  <RO.Api.Models.ItemScanCodesModel>
```

Comment: Just a thought: does your `ItemScanCodeModel` need to implement `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()` (the [`IEquatable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netcore-3.1) interface) for this to work?

Comment: Another thought: if you're comparing two collections to see if they have the same elements, `Assert.AreEqual()` isn't going to work.  You must use [`SequenceEqual()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Comment: Or use [fluent assertions](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/)